# Installation of Tripleo failed to install python-gnocchiclient, and python-pankoclient on Centos7

Tags: centos, centos7, openstack, tripleo

I am trying to install OpenStack since days, on Centos7 with Stein distribution I am installing the Undercloud via triplo repository but two stages are failing with errors, they are given below:

1. Failed to Install `python-gnocchiclient`

```
/Stage[main]/Gnocchi::Client/Package[python-gnocchiclient]/ensure: change from 'purged' to 'present' failed: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install python-gnocchiclient' returned 1: Error: Nothing to do"
```

2. Failed to Install `python-pankoclient`

```
Stage[main]/Panko::Client/Package[python-pankoclient]/ensure: change from 'purged' to 'present' failed: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install python-pankoclient' returned 1: Error: Nothing to do"
```

I am new to `Openstack`, and `Centos` Maybe I am missing something don't have a clue even tried to install them Manually could not find any luck in that as well.

Can anybody explain What is going wrong here?

**Update**: I am also receiving this error on the yum install command

```
https://trunk.rdoproject.org/centos7/af/f5/aff5d8f30d73cf34e9a52a0b070143f128e37e79_57e4b623/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

**Update**: Found the Package installation links

1. python-gnocchiclient

```
sudo yum install -y https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/python-gnocchiclient/7.0.4/1.el7/noarch/python2-gnocchiclient-7.0.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

2. python-pankoclient

```
sudo yum install -y https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/python-pankoclient/0.7.0/1.el7/noarch/python2-pankoclient-0.7.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

but I am wondering why dependencies of tripleo undercloud is breaking here if I have to manually install all of these things What is the use of this thing?

Comment: Check if you have your desired packages in your enabled repos with "yum search python-gnocchiclient". Also make sure to copy the url in the second error and check if this website exists in your browser or with curl. It seems like the url is invalid

Comment: I have added another update and for the link I will see if this exists.

Comment: What happens if you try to install those packages yourself? You posted command lines but failed to include the results.

Comment: Yes Now it is working with the given commands

Answer (score 0):

So far this is the only answer which is working for me, I found the Package installation links

1. python-gnocchiclient

```
sudo yum install -y https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/python-gnocchiclient/7.0.4/1.el7/noarch/python2-gnocchiclient-7.0.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

2. python-pankoclient

```
sudo yum install -y https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/python-pankoclient/0.7.0/1.el7/noarch/python2-pankoclient-0.7.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

afterwards openstack install command will work and complete successfully